# Code not working on Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Currently I am working on Phonegap , I have found a sample code for which I want to make it work for Phonegap but I could't .
One more thing I want to mention that here Jquery MObile 1.2.0 is used but I want to use Jquery mobile 1.3.2 and JQuery 2.1.1 ,cordova-3.4.0

Any help will be apreciated .Thanks in advance .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <style>
            #content {
                padding: 0;
                position : absolute !important;
                top : 40px !important; 
                right : 0;
                bottom : 40px !important; 
                left : 0 !important;    
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>   
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
        <script>
        $(document).on('pageinit', '#index',function(e,data){   
           var minZoomLevel = 12;

           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
              zoom: minZoomLevel,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="content">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML seems fine ...can u tell what is the error ur getting ?

Comment: @ Maven .I have received Logcat Message::: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined", source: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js (2) AND on Android device screen I am getting "First Page" two times in vertical order but there is no map .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for this code not working is that you are missing jQuery library. jQuery Mobile can't work without jQuery.

That's why you're receiving this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined",
>   source: code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js (2)
>   AND on Android device screen I am getting "First Page" two times in
>   vertical order but there is no map .

Comment: Then how should I add Jquery Library for this code . I have JQuery -2.1.1 file but it is not working ,Help me plz.

Comment: Of course it's not working, look at jQuery version your using. jQuery Mobile is locked to certain jQuery version range, best jQuery version for jQuery Mobile 1.2 is 1.8.3

Comment: It will not, I repeat, it will not work with any jQuery above 1.8.3. I told you we will solve this problem :)

Comment: No , It didn't solve my problem . I have added jquery-1.8.3.js file in html file .It giving one more error "Uncaught type error : $ is not defined "

Comment: Then add jQuery before jQuery Mobile. This error could mean: 1. jQuery was not initialized properly or 2. jQuery was initialized but after content that is trying to use it

Comment: Now there is only one Info message in Logcat :: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined", source: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js (2)

Comment: Can you update your question with every change you made to mentioned HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55476/discussion-between-shishupal-shakya-and-gajotres).

Comment: plz help me to solve my another question posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184971/code-not-working-on-phonegap-application-android . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

That means ur HTML can't detect the **PLATFORM** of mobile

To detect the operating system on the client machine, your script can analyze the value of navigator.appVersion or navigator.userAgent. Below is a simple example of a script that sets the variable OSName to reflect the actual client OS.

```
// This script sets OSName variable as follows:
// "Windows"    for all versions of Windows
// "MacOS"      for all versions of Macintosh OS
// "Linux"      for all versions of Linux
// "UNIX"       for all other UNIX flavors 
// "Unknown OS" indicates failure to detect the OS

var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code , currently I am working on Windows Xp but above code prints 'Your OS :' Linux .

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var platform = navigator.platform.substr(0,3);

</script>
```

- See more at: http://ultimatewebdevelopmenttutorial.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-detect-browser-platform-and-operating-system.html#sthash.etnEw1AP.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

Now working code for Phonegap Application is ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquerymobile/jquery-1.8.3.js"> </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 

         <style>
            #content {
                padding: 0;
                position : absolute !important;
                top : 40px !important; 
                right : 0;
                bottom : 40px !important; 
                left : 0 !important;    
            }
        </style>

        <script>        
        $(document).on('pageinit', '#index',function(e,data){   
           var minZoomLevel = 12;

           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
              zoom: minZoomLevel,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           });
                });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="content">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
            </div>

        </div>    

    </body>
</htm
```

l>