# Code not working on Phonegap Application -Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

I am new to Cross-Platform development . I have a piece of code which is not working properly . It gives 3 Info messages in Logcat .

First Message :

> "Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (8)

Second Info Message :

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .", source: file:///android_asset/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css (17)

Third Info Message :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (26)

Code is here : `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/index.css" />

        <title>gcm on phonegap </title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="file:///android_asset/www/CORDOVA_GCM_script.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/GCMPlugin.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            // Java script code goes here

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="app-status-div">
        <ul id="app-status-ul">
            <li>Cordova Google Cloud Messaging Plugin Demo</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated .Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

you even got line numbers with errors and still cant figure it out?

first - target-densitydpi=device-dpi - this meta tag is deprecated as first google search states.

regarding rest issues, how can we help if you have issues in javascript and css files which you didnt quote here..?

Comment: @ Marcin Mikolajczyk ,Here errors are shown in JQuerymobile.js file and jquery-mobile.css and these files are downloaded from http://jquerymobile.com/download/ ,it means there is any other error .I think that there is any file which is not instantiating properly due to that these errors are being generated . By identifying line numbers I only understand that there is any file which is not instantiating .

Comment: ok, I think I see the issue. You have wrong paths to all resources.. remove the "file:///" and set proper paths.

Answer (score 0):

remove this file:///android_asset/www/ from all linking page .

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>gcm on phonegap </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="CORDOVA_GCM_script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="GCMPlugin.js"></script>
```